# How to change the background color of a Passwordbox for WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called PasswordValidationRules

It's a simple class

```
    public bool validatePasswordRules(String text)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[,@#$])");
        bool isValid = regex.IsMatch(text);
        if (isValid)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {                
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I want to check the rules as the user types into a PasswordBox.

I would like to have it trigger only when 8 characters are typed and the background would change to green if "true", otherwise it should have a red background.

Comment: so you want it red when less than 8 characters, or just nothing until 8 characters, then red or green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I barely know `WPF`, but I would have done this way,

First create password validation extension for `String`

```
public static class Validate
{
    public static bool ValidatePassword(this String password)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[,@#$])");
        bool isValid = regex.IsMatch(password);
        if (isValid)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `PasswordChanged` event of the `PasswordBox`,

```
private void text_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (text.Password.Length >= 8)
    {
      if (text.Password.ValidatePassword())
      {
         text.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));
      }
      else
         text.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
    }
    else
      text.Background = SystemColors.WindowBrush;
 }
```

Comment: I like your code but anyway for the Event without clicking a button?

Comment: @softwareisfun, the event is `PasswordChanged`, it's raised when you type in `PasswordBox`. `XAML` looks like this: `<PasswordBox x:Name="text" PasswordChanged="text_PasswordChanged"/>`

Answer (score 0):

by reading your question i think you should try this in c# 
take a picture box behind the textbox and validate the textbox length, if the lenght is less then 8 characters change the backcolor of the picturebox to red and if its >= 8 then change the color to green ,Here is the code example :

```
         if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 8)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if ( textBox1.Text.Length < 8)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

use this code on validating event of your password textbox, and change the name of textbox1 to your textbox name 
Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Its a PasswordBox. Not a TextBox

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbox which acts as password box , it uses a password char  and this code is in c#, use the textbox and change its propert to password char and define the password character so it will display that character instead of text, and so it use as pasword box , as in wpf

Answer (score 0):

I use this as validating event so when press tab it changes the color, but if you want you can use it inside the button event , it will work the same, when you press the button it will verify the length of the password box and if its more then 8 it will change the color to green.